# Array vs vector vs tuples?

Tags: database, data-structures

I am a bit confused about the difference between *arrays*, *vectors*, and *tuples*.

**What's the difference?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer -

Arrays - Fixed size container of same type of objects

Vectors - Dynamic size container of same type of objects

Tuples - Dynamic size container of different type of objects

All of them preserve the order of insertions.

The difference between vector and array varies largely from language to language. For instance, in C++, vector is dynamic array (wrapper over primitive array). For java, there is `ArrayList` and `Vector` for dynamic container - the latter is thread safe.